# Colons in Apache Spark application path

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm submitting Apache Spark application to YARN programmatically:

```
package application.RestApplication;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientArguments;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args1) {
        String[] args = new String[] {
                "--class", "org.apache.spark.examples.JavaWordCount",
                "--jar", "/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar",
                "--arg", "hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/input/file.txt"
        };
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        ClientArguments cArgs = new ClientArguments(args);
        Client client = new Client(cArgs, config, sparkConf);
        client.run();
    }
}
```

I have problem with line: `"--arg", "hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/input/file.txt"` - more specifically with colons:

```
16/08/29 09:54:16 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "9000/input/plik2.txt"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:29)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.parseHostPort(Utils.scala:935)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.waitForSparkDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:547)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:247)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:749)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:71)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:747)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:774)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
```

How to write (as argument) path to file with colons? I try various combinations with slashes, backslashes, %3a, etc...

Comment: Have you tried just removing `hdfs://hadoop-master:9000`.  Most installations of Spark I have worked with default to HDFS.

Comment: Not works: http://wklej.org/id/2802613/ :(

Comment: Since it looks like you are running this on the command line, you could try wrapping your argument in single quotes `"'hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/input/file.txt'"`

Comment: In console works without "hdfs://hadoop-master:9000", but here (programmatically submit) no.

Comment: Where did you know about the arguments? What about `--arg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed program to: https://github.com/mahmoudparsian/data-algorithms-book/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dataalgorithms/chapB13/client/SubmitSparkPiToYARNFromJavaCode.java

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client;
import org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ClientArguments;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class SubmitSparkAppToYARNFromJavaCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        run(); 
    }
    static void run() throws Exception {
        String sparkExamplesJar = "/opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.11-2.0.0.jar";
        final String[] args = new String[]{
            "--jar",
            sparkExamplesJar,
            "--class",
            "org.apache.spark.examples.JavaWordCount",
            "--arg",
            "hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/input/file.txt"
        };
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.createConfiguration();     
        System.setProperty("SPARK_YARN_MODE", "true");
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf();
        sparkConf.setSparkHome(SPARK_HOME);
        sparkConf.setMaster("yarn");
        sparkConf.setAppName("spark-yarn");
        sparkConf.set("master", "yarn");
        sparkConf.set("spark.submit.deployMode", "cluster");
        ClientArguments clientArguments = new ClientArguments(args); 
        Client client = new Client(clientArguments, config, sparkConf);
        client.run();
    }
}
```

and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

According to `Utils#parseHostPort` which get invoked during that call, Spark seems to consider as port all the text that is behind last `:` :

```
def parseHostPort(hostPort: String): (String, Int) = {
    // Check cache first.
    val cached = hostPortParseResults.get(hostPort)
    if (cached != null) {
      return cached
    }

    val indx: Int = hostPort.lastIndexOf(':')
    // This is potentially broken - when dealing with ipv6 addresses for example, sigh ...
    // but then hadoop does not support ipv6 right now.
    // For now, we assume that if port exists, then it is valid - not check if it is an int > 0
    if (-1 == indx) {
      val retval = (hostPort, 0)
      hostPortParseResults.put(hostPort, retval)
      return retval
    }

    val retval = (hostPort.substring(0, indx).trim(), hostPort.substring(indx + 1).trim().toInt)
    hostPortParseResults.putIfAbsent(hostPort, retval)
    hostPortParseResults.get(hostPort)
}
```

As a consequence, the whole string `9000/input/file.txt` is supposed to be a single port number. Which suggests you are not supposed to refer to your input file from HDFS file system. I guess someone more skilled in Apache Spark would give you better advice.